# Which game has more powerful cantrips, Pathfinder or 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, spells, edition-comparison

I can read books myself, but without knowing any of those systems well numbers won't be very meaningful for me. I need those who have some experience in both of those games.

Basically, choosing the new game to master, I will probably pick the one with more powerful cantrips, just because I like the concept of having unlimited uses of some kind of magic, and GMs that I know typically don't advance too far in levels, so spell slots will be very limited.

It would probably be hard to guess which is powerful and which is not -- let's define power as being able to perform better or worse in rougly the same situation if a Pathfinder or 5e caster would act.

As far as I understand, cantrips are about way more than dealing damage in combat. How would both editions perform in out-of-combat situations compared to each other?

Comment: I think this is a loaded question simply because it is not simply dependent on just the cantrip but also how the entire system is set up like CRs are slightly different from 5E to 3.X/PF as well.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it's a [gorilla vs. shark question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/). There are too many ways in which these are different things that are not 1:1 comparable, but it will still attract opinions and arguments as people try to compare them anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take a straight-forward comparison, and look at *how often will I use cantrips?* then most likely 5e will come out ahead.

5e cantrips are designed to be a decent way to use your Action in combat throughout all levels, which means you'll use them a lot in fights. They even scale with your power.

Additionally, the non-combat cantrips tend to be flavorful and combine a number of different abilities to make you feel like a spellcaster. 5e's Minor Illusion is the combination of a cantrip *and* a 1st level spell in Pathfinder, for example. Each class also has a general "Do stuff that a [Class] should be able to do" cantrip. (Prestidigation for Arcane classes exists in 5e, but Clerics and Druids also get a more fitting alternative to it. These give you a ton of options to make use of your Cantrips.

5e also just has a lot less spell-slots in general. There is the expectation that your Cantrips are the general bread-and-butter of your class, so they define your character much more than they do in Pathfinder, where they are more of a "hm, I have no more options. Let's use a cantrip."

You will, for example, basically *never* see a 5e Wizard or Sorcerer walk around with a crossbow as backup.

OTOH, if you look at the single most useful Pathfinder Cantrip, then in 5e that one has been upgraded to a 1st level spell. That would be **Detect Magic** and not having it available 24/7 actually makes the game much more interesting.

Comment: This is a decent breakdown and basic comparison but without the OP reading and comparing *systems* it doesn't tell the whole story for them.